# how to solve org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException error in Apache Solr?

Tags: solr, lucene, indexing

Am using Apache Solr 3.1.0 with Lucene 3.1.0. While indexing server got stopped due to hardware failure. I restarted my server but solr indexing is not happening.

am getting

```
SEVERE: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexExceptio n: document count mismatch: deleted docs count 0 vs segment doc count 148 segmen t=_otm
```

It seems to be a bug in below 3.6 versions [reference](http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Lucene-and-Solr-updates-fix-index-corruption-bug-1343798.html). But how to upgrade to higher version with out losing the old indexes.

How to solve this. Any body can tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading won't fix your problem.

Have a look at [CheckIndex](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/CheckIndex.html) class. You can first run `checkIndex()` method (read-only) which would provide with the status information (`CheckIndex.Status`) and then you can run `fixIndex(CheckIndex.Status status)` in order to attempt to fix it. Good luck!